# Insert query in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to insert the value in  this way any help me out this code. 
It doesn't work for me . Error occurred as unknown column 'Fname1' in field list

```
app.post('/insert',function (req,res){
     var Fname1=req.body.fname;
    var Passwor1=req.body.pwd;
    var sql="insert into test(Fname,Passwor) values(Fname1,Passwor1)";
    con.query(sql,function(err,rows){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send("Value has been inserted");
    })
})
```

I don't want to insert  in this way.

```
var data = {
        Fname:req.body.fname,
        Passwor:req.body.pwd
        };

con.query("insert into test set ?",[data], function (err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send("Value has been inserted");
    })
```

Comment: can you update your table definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your `sql` emit the Fname1 and Passwor1 as variables;

```
 app.post('/insert',function (req,res){
         var Fname1=req.body.fname;
        var Passwor1=req.body.pwd;
        var sql= "insert into test(Fname,Passwor) values ('"+Fname1+"',  '"+Passwor1+"')";
        con.query(sql,function(err,rows){
                if(err) throw err;
                res.send("Value has been inserted");
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like the following:

```
"insert into test(Fname,Passwor) values ('"+Fname1+"',  '"+Passwor1+"')"
```

Comment: @chozhan Glad to help you.. Have a happy coding..Please accept the answer if it really helped you..

Comment: This works. But could be attacked by SQL Injection.
You should escape parameter like this.
    con.escape(Fname1)